# regular expression not matching for string

Tags: java, regex

When I tried to use the below regular expression to get the values, it is not matching.

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(\\d+),\\s(\\d+),\\s(\\d+),\\s(\\d+)");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("(8,0), (0,-1), (7,-2), (1,1)");

while (matcher.find()) {
    int x = Integer.parseInt(matcher.group(1));
    int y = Integer.parseInt(matcher.group(2));
    System.out.printf("x=%d, y=%d\n", x, y);
}
```

Can anyone please tell me some solution for this ?

Comment: what is your expected output. Are you trying to match the entire string or part of it?

Comment: What parts are you trying to match?  Have you tried using something like [Regex Tester](http://regexpal.com/) to test it?

Comment: i am trying to print all the four x and y values

Comment: What about the parentheses? What about the comma inside the parentheses?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can match `(x,y)` with `\\((\\d+),(\\d+)\\)` and if you also want to match negative values you can add `-` as an optional character. *i.e.* `\\((-?\\d+),(-?\\d+)\\)`

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\((-?\\d+),(-?\\d+)\\)");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("(8,0),(0,-1),(7,-2),(1,1)");

while (matcher.find()) {
   int x = Integer.parseInt(matcher.group(1));
   int y = Integer.parseInt(matcher.group(2));
   System.out.printf("x=%d, y=%d\n", x, y);
}
```

**OUTPUT**

```
x=8, y=0
x=0, y=-1
x=7, y=-2
x=1, y=1
```

In `\\((\\d+),(\\d+)\\)` we have two groups of `\\d+` which will match respective `x` and `y` coordinates and we have also escaped `(` and `)` to match brackets. For negative values we have added `-` as an optional character in both groups.

Comment: no it is not working I am having negative values too

Comment: @AlexMan Then something a little like `\((-)?(\d+),(-)?(\d+)\)` might work

Comment: @MadProgrammer wat is the difference between `(-)?(\d+)` and `(-?\\d+)`

Comment: @AlexMan Probably not much, my reg expression is pretty basic ;)